# socket emit - on fuction does not work properly in node js (using javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I wrote a serial port communication program

Through socket io i Implemente that When i select an option and press the connect button, the function is called from nodejs.

But I could not see anything in the server logs

I can see that the socket server is open.(a user connected)

Client:

```
<html>
  <FORM name="dmmsetting">
    <input type="button" name="connectdmm" value="connect" 
             onclick="connectport(dmmsetting)"></FORM>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    var socket = io.connect();  

    function connectport(dmmsetting)
    {
        if(dmmsetting.portdmm.options[1].selected){
            socket.emit('connect0');
            alert('connect0');
    };
  </script>
</html>
```

Server:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(httpServer);   

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){           
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });

  socket.on('connect0',function(data){
    portDMM.on('open',function(){
      if(err)
        console.log(err);
      else
        console.log('port DMM open');
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: You said you cannot see anything in the server logs, but you can see "A user connected"? What do you expect to see that you are not seeing?

Comment: i can't see 'port DMM open'

Comment: Well I'm not sure where `portDMM` comes from, but my expectation would be that the "open" event is not firing. All that happens when you fire the event "connect0" is a listener is bound to `portDMM`. What might trigger the  "open" event?

Comment: 'open' is a command for serial port open. portDMM is serial port's name. 
However, console.log (err) should not occur even if it does not open.

Comment: as @djfdev was saying, you are triggering the socket to run a function that is expecting the portDMM to fire. Nothing is triggering that, that's why the function with the if else statement will not be executed at all

Comment: Is the 'open' function coding wrong?

Comment: You have `if(err)` in the `portDMM.on('open', function() {...})` handler, but there's no variable by the name of `err` in scope.  Is it supposed to be `portDMM.on('open', function(err) {...})`?

Comment: Not sure that this is a socket issue, but you can check that by adding an error catcher. What happens if you place a simple console.log in your if block? Does it show in the server logs?